# jQuery animate left over time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a div slide to the right by increasing the position left I want it to slowly go from the left hand side to the right and then loop back to the start. At the moment I'm just trying to animate the position so it doesn't jump instantly-

```
$('#pig').css('left', 200).animate(300);
```

Comment: Adeneo's answer is correct. Be sure to check out the various easing functions available. If you want the greatest control and smoothest animation, though, CSS transitions are a good option.

Comment: Mm, You need to start after a while? What do you mean with "so it doesnt jump instantly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adeneo's answer is correct, but you also asked to loop back to the start. Assuming you want the div to go back to its original position, you need to chain another animation like this:

```
$('#pig').animate({left: 200}, 300, function() {
  $('#pig').animate({left: 0}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax is

```
$('#pig').animate({left: 200}, 300);
```

[jQuery.animate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

To add animations in a queue you can either just chain them

```
$('#pig').animate({left: 200}, 300).animate({left: 0}, 300);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wWzp5/2/)

or use the callback argument, or use jQuery's queue to set up as many animations as you'd like in a queue

```
$('#pig').queue(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: 200}, 300);
    $(this).animate({left: 0}, 300);
}).dequeue();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wWzp5/)

or to make it recursive, you can use a combination of both

```
(function ani() {
    $('#pig').queue(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: 200}, 300);
        $(this).animate({left: 0}, 300, ani);
    }).dequeue();
}());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wWzp5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#pig')
        .css('left', 200)
        .animate(300)
}, 1000)
```